# Zend 2 : Unable to render template

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have an error in my Zend Framework 2 project, I try to add a new view named " Blog "

I created the module.config and indexController, and the view but always I get this error and I don't know why :

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template
>   "blog/index/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file

the module.config code

```
<?php

namespace Blog;

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /blog/:controller/:action
            'blog' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/blog',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Blog\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            //'Blog\Controller\Index' => 'Blog\Controller\IndexController'
            'Blog\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);

?>
```

the indexController code :

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
?>
```

and finally my structure folders is like this :

[image]

I use version 2.4.13

Answer (score 3):

The `src` folder should only contain PHP classes, your view templates should not be in there. Move the view folder up a level and it should work.

Take a look at the folder structure of the ZF skeleton app as a reference: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tree/master/module/Application